# Conditional async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gmail

I have my function getting an email from Gmail. I want to run this function  n times or until an email is found.

What is a proper way to do it? I tried: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#retry but without success.

I was following this article how to read emails:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) ?

Comment: Please can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Does the function return a Promise or receives a callback?

Comment: @samsonthehero it receives a callback

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a routine called `gmail`, which returns a promise which succeeds (fulfills) if an email is found, and otherwise fails (rejects), then:

```
function get(n) {
  return gmail().catch(() => {
    if (!n) throw "Too many tries!";
    return get(--n);
   };
}
```

Usage:

```
get(5).then(
  mail => console.log(mail.body),
  () => console.log("No mail!"));
```

If for some reason you do not like the recursive style:

```
function get(n) {
  let promise = Promise.reject();

  do { promise = promise.catch(gmail); } while (n--);

  return promise;
}
```

If `gmail` is callback style, then

```
function get(n, cb) {
  gmail(function(err, data) {
    if (err) 
      if (!n) get(--n, cb); 
      else cb("Too many tries!");
    else cb(null, data);
  });
}
```

Or better yet, promisify `gmail`, either using a library or

```
function promisify(fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    fn(function(data, err) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

and then replace `gmail` in the first solution with `promisify(gmail)`.

Comment: unfortunately my function does not return a promise. I guess recursion is the way to go?

Comment: @dzvert use the solution above, but use the callback, or wrap the API as a function that returns a promise ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises))

Comment: @samsonthehero I've already tried that but getting "then is not a function" error.